# Multiple Windows Forms on one application

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

I have two windows forms, first is initial and second is invoked when button on the first is pressed. It's two different windows, with different tasks. I programmed for both MVP pattern.
But in the Main() I have this:

```csh
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    ViewFirst viewFirst = new ViewFirst();//First Form
    PresenterFirst presenterFirst = new PresenterFirst(viewFirst);
    Application.Run(viewFirst);
}
```

And I Have Second Windows Form:

```csh
ViewSecond viewSecond = new ViewSecond();//Second Form
PresenterSecond presenterSecond = new PresenterSecond(viewSecond);
```

I want to run it in this app as soon as the button on the first is clicked. How could I do this? My button on the first WF is:

```csh
private void history_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewSecond db = new ViewSecond();//second Form where I have sepparate WF.
    db.Show();
}
```

Comment: The code you have looks like it should work - what's the problem?

Comment: Application.Run(view); It runs only the first form. I also need to run second form. Something like this : Application.Run(viewFirst); Application.Run(viewSecond);

Comment: And what happens when you click the button that's supposed to show the second form?

Comment: It shows the second form, but nothing is working there. No buttons clicking, doesn't take inputs from textBoxes, logic is not working. When I wrote in Main() {... Application.Run(viewFirst); Application.Run(viewSecond);}. First it started FirstForm, then when I close it, SecondForm is started, and only now logic is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Application.Run(Form mainForm)` may only run ONE form per thread. If you try to run a second form on the same thread using `Application.Run`, the following exception might be thrown

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled

Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid operation. Use
Form.ShowDialog instead.
```

So, if you would like to call `Application.Run` to run another `Form`, you may call it under a new thread.

**Example**

```
private void history_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread myThread = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate { Application.Run(new ViewSecond()); }); //Initialize a new Thread of name myThread to call Application.Run() on a new instance of ViewSecond
    //myThread.TrySetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); //If you receive errors, comment this out; use this when doing interop with STA COM objects.
    myThread.Start(); //Start the thread; Run the form
}
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: @ShukhratRaimov No problems! Glad I could help. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you are setting the presenter for your second form.  You should set it when you are creating the ViewSecond form.  Try this in the button click event:

```
private void history_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewSecond viewSecond = new ViewSecond();//Second Form
    PresenterSecond presenterSecond = new PresenterSecond(viewSecond);
    db.Show();
}
```